# Ext JS store load listener not work

Tags: extjs, web-applications

I want to save value received by AJAX response to Ext JS proxy in a JavaScript array. My code look like this:

```
var nodelist = [];
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Nodes',
    url: 'sequencing',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'sequencing',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Nodes'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        'load': function() {
            var StoreLength = store.data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < StoreLength; i++) {
                nodelist.push(store.data.items[i].data.text);
            };
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
store.load();
var node_rec = nodelist;
```

But the `store.load();` does not call the `load` listener above? Can some one solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is any data actually being loaded? Check your URL parameter

Comment: the URL finely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[store.load()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) is called at the exit of current event handler. Loading of a data store happens asynchronously so by the time it loads the store the execution continues from the next line. So you cannot directly use the nodelist variable after calling load because load will not be called at that point so nodelist will be empty even though the store gets populated eventually.

So you can add a callback to the load method which gets called once the store loads.

```
store.load({
    callback: function(records){
        console.log(records); //verify whether you are getting records from the URL     
    }
});
```